# Optimize query for records that have match both values

Tags: oracle, optimization

I am trying to optimize an Oracle query.  Right now it runs pretty slow since the table has ~1M records. I have two tables, the `item_location` table, and the `tariffs` table.  An `item_location` record has a dual key, the `item_no` and `item_loc`.  The `tariffs` records are stored with a key `tariff_code` which is a random three-digit identifier, with fields `import_tariff` and `export_tariff`.  The `item_tariff_code` is the foreign key for the item's `tariffs` record.

Here is an [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ae221/1) for simplicity.

I am trying to find the `item_no` with locations that have `export_tariff`'s that match two values inclusive.

For example, if I want to find items with `export_tariff` equal to both "1111111111" and "2222222222", it would return "12345" because these records were in the database:

```
  item_no  |  item_loc  |  export_tariff
----------------------------------------
  12345    |  B1        |  1111111111
  12345    |  B2        |  2222222222
```

But it shouldn't find "67890" because of this record:

```
  item_no  |  item_loc  |  export_tariff
----------------------------------------
  67890    |  B1        |  1111111111
```

Since it doesn't have `export_tariff` "2222222222".

I've added the query I've been using so far in the [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ae221/1).

Comment: I don't think I can, I simplified and renamed the actual tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you cannot use temp tables, Oracle has the WITH clause that can be used in pretty much the same way:

```
WITH t as (SELECT tariff_code FROM tariffs WHERE 
    (export_tariff LIKE '3916906000%' OR export_tariff LIKE '39191080%'))
SELECT t1.item_no FROM
(SELECT * FROM item_location il, t WHERE il.item_tariff_code = t.tariff_code) t1,
(SELECT * FROM item_location il, t WHERE il.item_tariff_code = t.tariff_code) t2
WHERE t1.item_no = t2.item_no AND t1.item_tariff_code <> t2.item_tariff_code
```

Thanks for SQLFiddle by the way, it's a great site.

PS: I can't see how to avoid the scanning of the `item_location` table twice, because you really have to do the join on `item_no`. If you want to get that out of the way quickly, you can turn around the order of execution with a query like this:

```
WITH il AS (
  SELECT
    il1.item_no,
    il1.item_tariff_code AS tc1,
    il2.item_tariff_code AS tc2
  FROM item_location il1
  JOIN item_location il2
    ON il1.item_no = il2.item_no AND
       il1.item_loc <> il2.item_loc)
SELECT item_no FROM il
JOIN tariffs t1
  ON il.tc1 = t1.tariff_code
JOIN tariffs t2
  ON il.tc2 = t2.tariff_code
WHERE
  t1.export_tariff LIKE '3916906000%' AND
  t2.export_tariff LIKE '39191080%'
```

See it at [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/42d0a/21)

Comment: Interesting solution, but unfortunately I'm working in a pretty regulated environment. These tables exist in our ERP software, so physically creating a new table won't be feasible.

Comment: I've modified the answer to use WITH instead of a temp table.

Comment: Awesome! This speeds up the queries I'm running significantly.

Answer (score 0):

If you are indexed on export_tariff, perhaps you can do two indexed lookups and combine the results to find the items of interest?

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.item_no, a.item_loc
  FROM ( SELECT item_no, item_loc
           FROM item_location
           WHERE export_tariff = '1111111111'
       ) a
      ,( SELECT item_no, item_loc
           FROM item_location
           WHERE export_tariff = '2222222222'
       ) b
  WHERE a.item_no = b.item_no
```

Comment: Sorry, your query runs slower than the existing one.  The `tariffs` table is indexed on the `export_tariff`, but the `item_location` table is the big one.  So your query is accessing that table twice, which is slowing it down.

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following should work:

```
SELECT
  FIRST.ITEM_NO, FIRST.ITEM_LOC, FIRST.ITEM_TARIFF_CODE, FIRST.EXPORT_TARIFF, SECOND.ITEM_TARIFF_CODE, SECOND.EXPORT_TARIFF
FROM (
   -- using a simple inner join of item_location and tariffs,
   -- create a right outer join by joining the inner join on itself 
    SELECT A.ITEM_NO, A.ITEM_LOC, A.ITEM_TARIFF_CODE, B.EXPORT_TARIFF
    FROM
      ITEM_LOCATION A INNER JOIN TARIFFS B ON (A.ITEM_TARIFF_CODE = B.TARIFF_CODE)
    ) FIRST
  RIGHT OUTER JOIN (
    -- SAME INNER JOIN
    SELECT A.ITEM_NO, A.ITEM_LOC, A.ITEM_TARIFF_CODE, B.EXPORT_TARIFF
    FROM
      ITEM_LOCATION A INNER JOIN TARIFFS B ON (A.ITEM_TARIFF_CODE = B.TARIFF_CODE)
    ) SECOND
  ON (FIRST.ITEM_NO = SECOND.ITEM_NO)
WHERE
  -- select the export tariffs you want
  FIRST.EXPORT_TARIFF = '6808417805' AND SECOND.EXPORT_TARIFF = '6046232842'
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
SELECT 
  l1.item_no
FROM 
  item_location AS l1
CROSS JOIN
  item_location AS l2 ON l2.item_no = l1.item_no
JOIN 
  tariffs AS t1 ON l1.item_tariff_code = t1.tariff_code
JOIN
  tariffs AS t2 ON l2.item_tariff_code = t2.tariff_code
WHERE
  t1.export_tariff LIKE '1111111111' 
  AND
  t2.export_tariff LIKE '2222222222'
```